# Django rest framework serializer dynamic fields with many=True

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want my serializer return fields dynamically depends on value of some model field. So I override `get_fields` method.

Here's the code example:

```
class TestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    options = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    blanks = serializers.StringRelatedField()

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('id', 'category', 'options', 'blanks')

    def get_fields(self):
        fields = super().get_fields()
        if self.instance.category == 'FirstCategory':
            del fields['options']
        else:
            del fields['blanks']
        return fields
```

This works fine when to serialize a single model, but if pass `many=True` for multiple models, it fails. The `self.instance` is a `QuerySet`.

How can I deal with this situation?

Comment: You need to *return* `fields` in `get_fields` at the end.

Comment: THX, It's a typing mistake, and I've added _return_ statement at the end.